# How to save MultyAutoCompleteTextView in firestore as boolean?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I don't know if this is possible..
the user will enter strings in `MultyAutoCompleteTextView`, for example:

football,  basketball, baseball,

I want to save them in `firestore` as this:

> football: true
>
> basketball: true
>
> baseball: true

How can I do that?

Note: I'm using `HashMap` to load data to `firestore` and not java class module:

```
private static final String KEY_TAGS = "sports";


final String sport = sportF.getText().toString().trim();
final String[] sportSingle = sport.split("\\s*,\\s*");
final List<String> tags = Arrays.asList(sportSingle);
Map<String, Object> stdFile = new HashMap<>();
stdFile.put(KEY_TAGS, tags);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < sportSingle.length ; i++){
   stdFile.put(sportSingle[i] , true);
}
```